How to give CI container access to other containers in GitHub Actions with Docker
In our CI/CD setup, we're using GitHub Actions to start a couple of Docker containers and execute some tests which depend on those Docker containers.
Here's the workflow to run the tests:
jobs:
  check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      <setup steps omitted for brevity>
      - name: Test
        run: |
          docker compose --file ./docker/docker-compose.test.yml up -d
          npm run test

The Docker Compose file (./docker/docker-compose.test.yml) is just a simple MongoDB instance:
services:
    database:
        image: mongo:5.0.4
        # volumes:
        #   - ./db:/data/db
        ports:
            - '27017:27017'
        environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=<hidden>
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=<hidden>
            - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=<hidden>

Recently, I discovered we can use a CI image to containerize our tools for use on GitHub Actions, rather than installing the tools in every workflow run.
I have made a CI image and pushed it to dockerhub: https://hub.docker.com/r/prosopo/ci
I have then modified the workflow to run using the CI image as a container:
jobs:
  check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: 
        image: prosopo/ci:latest
        options: >
            --volume ${{ github.workspace }}:/repo
    steps:
      <setup steps omitted for brevity>
      - name: Test
        run: |
          docker compose --file ./docker/docker-compose.test.yml up -d
          npm run test

However, here's where I hit a snag. The npm run test runs some JS tests which expect MongoDB to be at localhost:27017. When you're running this from the host machine, this works. But running from a container, i.e. the CI container, localhost resolves to the CI container rather than the host machine where the 27017 port is published. I read that this is host vs. container networking. So I adjusted the tests to point at docker-database-1:27017 (which is the name of the MongoDB container) and added the MongoDB and CI containers to the same network.
Adjusted Docker Compose file:
services:
    database:
        image: mongo:5.0.4
        # volumes:
        #   - ./db:/data/db
        ports:
            - '27017:27017'
        networks:
            - pronet
        environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=<hidden>
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=<hidden>
            - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=<hidden>
networks:
    pronet:
        driver: bridge

then in the workflow:
jobs:
  check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: 
        image: prosopo/ci:latest
        options: >
            --volume ${{ github.workspace }}:/repo
    steps:
      <setup steps omitted for brevity>
      - name: Test
        run: |
          docker network connect pronet $(docker ps | grep prosopo/ci:latest | awk '{print $NF}')
          docker compose --file ./docker/docker-compose.test.yml up -d
          npm run test

GitHub does not let you specify the --network arg for the ci container, so I've had to add it to the network manually before testing.
This seems like a clunky setup because:

you have to manually add the CI image to the network
all our Docker Compose files now need a network which the CI container can join to talk to the containers
the tests now no longer run unless you're running from a container in the same network - you can't run npm run test from the host machine because docker-database-1 will not resolve (I can solve this via environment variable to switch between docker-database-1 and localhost depending on CI environment or not, but seems clunky!)
the container name for the CI container is a random string, so I have to grep for it each run, which is rather brittle.

Is there a better way to do this? Storing our tools in a CI image is super handy for us to avoid long install times and maintain consistent tooling, so I'd like to make this work. But we need to be able to run the tests locally using localhost:27017 as the target as well as running tests in CI/CD.
I've read that we could use GitHub services for this and GitHub automatically manages the network for you. However, this runs the containers in parallel to the workflow job, meaning the Docker image must be available ahead of time. In another one of our workflows, we're building the image for a dependent container and running some different tests - the service containers wouldn't work here because the image is not available before the job starts.

s there a better way to do this? write everything inside docker-compose.yml

Why can not mongo run as a GitHub service?

It could, but what if I were building the image during the workflow?

If you build an image that you need to run as a service you can pass it to the job that runs the service. Here is a quick prototype that shows how it works:
name: service
on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      image: ${{ steps.set.outputs.image }}
    steps:
      - id: set
        run: echo "image=redis" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

  container-job:
    needs: setup
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: node:18

    services:
      redis:
        image: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.image }}

    steps:
      - name: Install Redis CLI
        run: |
          apt-get update
          apt-get install -y redis-tools
      - name: Check Redis service
        run: |
          redis-cli -h redis -p 6379 ping


Okay that does help, thank you. What does this do regarding the networking?

If you run my workflow, you will see in the logs that GitHub creates a network and connects both containers to it. I updated the answer.
